# Camera moving weirdly in godot

Tags: camera, godot

Camera moves like a zigzag in godot and makes me very uncomfortable
I tried several solutions including how to fix jitter videos and an addon but none seemed to fix the problem
I use an interpolated camera to follow the player, and the player moves smoothly so I assume the problem is with the camera, there's no code attatched to the camera and its target is a node I put behind the player

[Video of the problem](https://youtu.be/yKh4e93E0qY)

Image of the camere settings that I've changed

[image]

Comment: I don't know. Two things comes to mind: changing the `speed`, and increasing the `process_priority`. - I have moved away from `InterpolatedCamera` anyway, as it does not provide enough control over what it does.

Comment: Welcome to a stackexchange site! If you've managed to fix the issue described in the question, then please provide an answer and mark it as accepted, this will let folks know 1) that the issue has been solved, and 2) will let others know how they could fix this issue whenever they get it.